# Balance Mic and Speaker for Camera Input with Ground Loop Isolation

Tags: audio, microphone, speakers, ground-loop, differential-amplifier

Novice looking for some help.

I use a Cardo Bluetooth headset to communicate with friends and record the audio onto an action camera while out riding motorcycles. By trial and error I was able to come up with this circuit which has worked reasonably well for years.

[image: Cardo Comms]

I'm taking the my audio from the Cardo communicator microphone and combining it with the audio from my friends over the communicator (Helmet Speaker). A voltage divider (again by trial and error) gives me more or less balanced audio for my action camera with stereo Mic Input.

There is NO CONTINUITY between the Mic and Helmet Speaker. Without the isolation transformer the Communicator shuts off. The circuit needs to be very small (to tuck into a helmet) and be passive since I can't provide additional power. I suspect my current circuit gives me 20mins less use on the communicator but this is just based on observations with other units.

My action camera (Sony FDR X3000) takes a stereo Mic input. It seems to do some audio balancing internally but if the Helmet Speaker volume is very high or the Helmet Microphone is very high I occasionally get problems (one of the channels gets crushed), but under normal conditions it works well (example below - no gain adjustments on my PC).

[image: audio tracks]

This works most of the time but is there a better / simpler way to do what I'm trying to do? Unfortunately I don't have any fancy gear like an oscilloscope.

Comment: so - SPK OUT/SPK IN is basically a tap across the speaker connection. You say the camera has a stereo mic in, but you show only two terminals (unbalanced stereo has to be three. I'm a bit confused about Mic IN/ Mic OUT. Cam OUT goes TO the camera? When you say IN and OUT here do you mean IN to the interface or OUT from it to another device?  Could you perhaps improve your diagram to explicitly show the connections to other devices? it might help to show the Cardo thing on one side and the action cam on the other. thank you.

Comment: another question - using a multimeter to test resistance, can you figure out if the Cardo speaker and mic connections have a common "ground" (it won't really be ground but common for the device) connection? also, as the mic input to the camera is stereo, have you considered trying recording the speaker (audio from your friends) on one channel and you own mic on the other? that way, you won't need to mix them, which i what you are doing now.

Comment: https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4271499 - reading this, it sounds as if the AGC on the external mic input for that Sony cam really sucks, so quite likely the overload issues you are experiencing are not caused by your interface.

Comment: @danmcb Thank you very much for your inputs. I have updated the post with a new diagram which I hope makes more sense. I've also added a snip from an audio recording showing the audio on the left and right channel as it is currently working under normal use. I used a multimeter to test the cardo unit, there seems to be no continuity between the Cardo mic and speakers. Originally I tried to join all the 'commons' together without the isolation transformer but the Cardo just powers off immediately. It works well most of the time but would like to know if there is a better way. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will improve much on what you have done here. The transformer is needed as the mic and LS common connections on the cardio are not connected, as is the resistive divider to level match.

It seems from the discussion at [this link](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4271499) the Sony cam has some auto gain control (AGC) on the external mic in, which by the sound of it sets the signal rather high. You can't do anything about this, it is built into the Sony. The AGC will take the average of left and right mic input signals and adjust gain - that is why you see the engine noise from the helmet mic dip when someone talks over the communicator. You could play with the values of the two attenuator resistors, if the amount of dip is too much you could (for example) change the 100R to 47R (approximately 6dB less level) which will reduce the amount of AGC gain reduction. But quite likely this is not really a problem and you most likely already tuned these two resistor values. I think it is good to record mic and cardio to separate mic channels as this allows you to alter them independently in post (some video editor like Davinci Resolve would allow this).

But given that the interface needs to be passive and must isolate the mic from the speaker, I don't think you can simplify this any further. It's a pretty good job actually, given the restrictions you are under.